# Animated item in BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, bottomnavigationview

I am working on an Android Application in which I want to show animated item in menu of bottomnavigation. I have tried to search but it only gives me animation during transition(I have used animated-selector for this). I want animation for the whole time irrespective of icon's state.

Comment: Simple Animations can be done by programming using loops, coroutines etc, for easy way you can use GIFs at that place, use library https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable to show animated GIFs in place of images